# HTML / JavaScript auto-updating POST request listener

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl, post

Edited for ease of reading:

Looking to write a webpage on my server. The use of the page is this:
I will be creating USB drives with an auto run script to simply call out to my server with the name of the user who's currently logged into the machine that the drive is plugged into. Here's the predicament: I don't know how to code the webpage to display the data it receives from the scripts sending the usernames. Any assistance is appreciated, I'll include what I'm envisioning the webpage to look like below. 

`Callback Users:`

`username 1`

`username 2`

Comment: Very Vague question - Do you have any examples of what you have already tried?

Comment: I have no clue how to start. I know how to create a webpage, I just don't know how to get the data out of a post to put in the page itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this as a start

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('username: ','api_key: '));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
 header('Location: index.php');
```

Notice the header('Location: index.php'); That redirects you to a different page after the curl is executed. If you are going to a location on the same site, you can use this and GET commands to do what you would like. If they are on separate domains I would consider doing more research into CURL.